# Function regex_extract in hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, extract

I'm extracting information from logs in hive with this sentences:

```
regexp_extract(values, "^(\\w{3} \\s?\\d+ \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d \\w+-\\w+ \\w+:) (\\[)(\\d{2})(\\/)(\\w{3})(\\/)(\\d{4})(.*\\])",3)day, 
regexp_extract(values, "^(\\w{3} \\s?\\d+ \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d \\w+-\\w+ \\w+:) (\\[)(\\d{2})(\\/)(\\w{3})(\\/)(\\d{4})(.*\\])",5)month
```

I use the same regular expression for extract two fields in two different regex_extract call. It is possible to extract more than one field only executing regex_extract once?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but if your *really* want to have one extraction that will give you multiple fields instead of one, this is what I found:

http://dev.bizo.com/2012/01/using-genericudfs-to-return-multiple.html

Note that for this solution you need to write a UDF with object inspectors, but see for yourself.